# Как вывести рейтинг именно US?

Tags: javascript, php

**Я выполняю запрос**

```
<?php foreach($tv_id_re->content_ratings->results as $re){ ?>
       <p><h2 id="rate"><?php echo $re->rating; ?></h2></p>
<?php }   ?>
```

**Получаю ответ**

```
content_ratings":{"results":[{"iso_3166_1":"DE","rating":"16"},{"iso_3166_1":"US","rating":"TV-MA"}]}
```

16

TV-MA

**Как мне выполнить запрос чтобы получить только рейтинг US?**

Comment: Проверить что `iso_3166_1` равно `US`?

Comment: Я получаю список с рейтингами огромный мне нужно вывести только значение rating от США (TV-MA или будет другое значение) который я уже получаю с рейтингом других стран

Comment: Ну и что вы попробовали сделать для решения своей задачи?

Comment: @АлинаХром дайте пример входящих данных - сделаю пример.

Comment: @Denis640Kb уже есть в задаче пример. Человек просто `if` не знает как написать.

Comment: @Denis640Kb`"content_ratings": {
    "results": [
      {
        "iso_3166_1": "DE",
        "rating": "16"
      },
      {
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "rating": "TV-MA"
      }
    ]
  }` **Вот массив** получаю [1]DE:16 [2]US:TV-MA пыталась применить фильтр без толку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я даже не знаю что тут сложного:

```
<?php foreach($tv_id_re->content_ratings->results as $re){ 
    if ('US' === $re->iso_3166_1) {?>
       <p><h2 id="rate"><?php echo $re->rating; ?></h2></p>
<?php
        break; // чтобы оставшиеся элементы не просматривать
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Большое! Я не сильна в массивах. А как например этим же кодом вывести только первое значение?

Comment: Первое значение это `$tv_id_re->content_ratings->results[0]`.

Comment: Благодарю. Спасибо!